# I need a suggestion on query tuning techiniques

Tags: oracle10g, database-tuning

```
select /* all_rows */x1,x2,x3 
from view_x
where x1 in 
(select a.b1 from mytable a,mytable2 b
where a.b2=b.c2)
```

as `view_x` is a view, which is trying to get the data from the other source`(@othertable_dblink`)

I have index on b1. but as view_x is a view , I don't have privilege to create a index on that.

**NOTE:** Due to this, the mytable and mytable2 are going on error like "table access full"

**My Question:** How can I reduce the time on this, by not allowing it to go for "table access full"

if there are any query tuning techniques , pls let me know.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. b1? @othertable_dblink?

Comment: Some of the first steps for query tuning are 1) Defining the problem - how much data is being retrieved, how long does it take, how long should it take. 2) Looking at the explain plan to see how the statement is executing.  Run `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.displaly);`.  With that information the problem might be obvious and someone can answer, or more likely we will need even more information.

Answer (score 3):

"Table access full" is not an error, it's a data access path. Sometimes it's even the optimal one.

If you're sure the performance problem is on the sub-select, to speed that up the optimal indexes are likely:

- Index on `mytable2(c2)`
- Index on `mytable1(b2,b1)` (in that order)

The fields that need to be indexed to be useful for the join are `mytable2.c2` and `mytable1.b2`, an index on `mytable.b1` alone won't help for the join at all.

But depending on the size of the tables and the number of rows returned by that join, full scans might be the fastest option.